# j2ee pattern for centralizing the process of looking up services

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

which j2ee pattern is used for centralizing the process of looking up services:-

1. interface factory
2. intercepting filter
3. business delegate
4. service locator

Comment: Is that an interview question?

Comment: @John yes, i was asked in eBay interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [service locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) can be used for looking up services as described in [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servicelocator-137181.html). Please notice that this pattern can be considered a bit "outdated" and arguably dependency injection should be preferred in most cases (see [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) for a more elaborate discussion).